# ASP.NET: tag helper do not work. Where start debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading Adam Freeman "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2" book and following the book's project SportsStore. 
I'm having problem with tag helpers, when I'm running the project the navigation links in the bottom do not work, instead I see a tag helper in page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SportsStore V2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    <div>
        <h3>Kayak</h3>
        A boat for one person
        <h4>275,00 &#x20AC;</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Lifejacket</h3>
        Protective and fashionable
        <h4>48,95 &#x20AC;</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Soccer Ball</h3>
        FIFA-approved size and weight
        <h4>19,50 &#x20AC;</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Corner Flags</h3>
        Give your playing field a professional touch
        <h4>34,95 &#x20AC;</h4>
    </div>

<div page-model="SportsStoreApp.Models.ViewModels.PagingInfo" page-action="List"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code of List.cshtml

```
@model ProductListViewModel

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    <div>
        <h3>@p.Name</h3>
        @p.Description
        <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    </div>
}

<div page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-action="List"></div>
```

The code of PageLinkTagHelper class

```
namespace SportsStoreApp.Infrastructure
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "page-model")]
    public class PageLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;

        public PageLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
        {
            urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
        }

        [ViewContext]
        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public PagingInfo PageModel { get; set; }
        public string PageAction { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");

            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction, new {productPage = i});
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
                result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
            }

            output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

As I don't have experience with ASP.NET nor MVC, I don't understand how should I start to troubleshoot this problem?

PS I tried to rewrite from scratch, no result.

Comment: did you add your assembly in the viewimports? that always gets me

Comment: yes, I've tried to put _ViewImports.cshtml to the same folder as List.cshtml and to the root of Views folder
using SportsStoreApp.Models
using SportsStoreApp.Models.ViewModels
addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
addTagHelper SportsStoreApp.Infrastructure.*, SportsStore

Answer (score 0):

I've jumped over to the chapter about TagHelpers and there was written what actually registering taghelper means, it was a naming issue/typo/scope error.

When I registered TagHelper in _ViewsImport, I've used an assembly name from he book - SportsStore. But in my project I wanted to make a difference between Solution name and Project name, so my solution name was SportsSotreV2 and project name (assembly name) SportsStoreApp. So changing

@addTagHelper SportsStoreApp.Infrastructure.*, SportsStore

to

@addTagHelper SportsStoreApp.Infrastructure.*, SportsStoreApp

solved the problem.